# VMware Tools "Unable to start services"

Tags: xubuntu, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am unable to get vmware tools to work in xubuntu guest, on vmware workstation 10 on windows 8.1 host. I keep getting this message below:

```
Disabling timer-based audio scheduling in pulseaudio.
Detected X server version 1.14.5
Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.
Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included.
Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
initctl: Unknown job: vmware-tools-thinprint
Unable to start services for VMware Tools

Execution aborted.

Found VMware Tools CDROM mounted at /media/bogo-sort/VMware Tools. Ejecting 
device /dev/sr1 ...
```

I thought I could do without it, however the audio "skips" and none of the shared folders are available.